# What to do if answers are incorrect; but have some advices

Tags: discussion, support, answers, voting, upvotes

I asked a question and got some answers, after reading all answers, I could find the correct way; because all answers have good advices and introduce good references. So they seems to be *useful* and I can up-vote them, but at the other hand no one of them is *totally correct* and has *incorrect conclusion*. So voting them as useful posts, can be misleading for other readers, even I add comment to those answers.

Do I have to vote to them as useful posts? Of course I can answer to my question; but I want to know what I have to do with those answers?

Comment: "Do I have to vote to them as useful posts?" You don't have to do anything. Voting and accepting answers is your privilege but not a duty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How you vote is entirely up to you.

Although if you believe the answer can be misleading (or if it's just straight-up incorrect), that would typically be a sign that you should **not** upvote it (and possibly downvote it), even if it has other merits.

The ideal, if possible, would be to leave a comment pointing out the problem in order to get them to fix it (or just to have it be a signal to other readers, although Stack Exchange apparently disapproves of that sort of thing). After they've done this it would be a useful correct answer, which seems fine to upvote (again: if you want to).

Alternatively, or additionally, you can post an answer of your own. This would be especially applicable if none of the answers give a *complete* answer. Posting an answer you feel is superior to all the other answers is exactly what we want people to do.

It shouldn't really matter whether this is related to your own question or someone else's (people might tend to be *a bit* more generous with their upvotes on answers to their own question, but it shouldn't be to an extent where you're upvoting incorrect things).

Answer (score 5):

You have some options here, but it's up to your best judgement to decide which one applies.

You can:

- Answer your own question, linking to each answer that was useful to you, and ultimately explain how you applied what was given there, and how your solution was more unique than what anyone else posted (this is perfectly okay!). This is useful when you get *lots* of answers, or when you combine two or more different approaches. Ever find yourself wanting to accept 2 or more answers? It's something to consider. Consider up-voting what was useful, though (see below bullets in addition)
- Edit, or suggest an edit to the answer *if the technical inaccuracy* is minor, and leave a comment noting the change. You can also comment *prior* to making the edit. Comments that point out technical inaccuracies *in the form of edit collaboration* tend to stick around, despite the ephemeral nature of comments. Don't count on this, however.
- The "meh" vote. You don't vote up or down, and you can optionally leave a comment that indicates what's not optimal about the answer. Again, a comment that could easily become a minor edit is desirable.
- If it's just plain wrong, or way off base, or any suggestion on how to fix it basically begins with "Start over completely .." -- you can use your down vote. You can, if you want, also leave a comment like "Are you *certain* you saw [thing] in my example?" in addition to, or in lieu of, down voting. It's up to you.

You can also just downvote and move on. We don't require an explanation, but if you think you can provide one within the space of the level of engagement you're willing to give, then great! Feedback on how to get better is always more useful than "this needs to be better", but it's up to you.

#### Always look inward, too!

If a number of answers aren't *quite* understanding something, or seem to be suboptimal for random reasons, maybe make *sure* you've clearly stated what you need to accomplish and *all* constraints, even unreasonable ones? (we all have 'em from time to time). Remember that folks can't look 10 steps ahead into your code base like you can when you evaluate the potential efficacy of any given suggestion, so try to be *really* clear about what you need.